# How to delete iCloud documents?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I'm using a UIDocument with iCloud. I'm not using CoreData. What's the best way to delete a UIDocument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To delete the document from iCloud, first you have to get the filename you want to delete. and then you can delete it using NSFileManager.

```
NSString *saveFileName = @"Report.pdf";
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[filemgr removeItemAtURL:ubiquitousPackage error:nil];
```

This is the way, which i used to delete document, Check it out.
It is woking great for me.
Thanks

Comment: According to the docs you have to delete stuff async on a background queue. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW4

Comment: Where this works it does not take advantage of `UIDocument`'s implementation of `NSFileCoordinator` Adrian Sarli's answer is better.

Comment: For reference, please note that `removeItemAtURL:` will not delete the document if it has not yet been downloaded from iCloud to the device.

Comment: I have used this solution in the past but iCloud works like crap on iOS and this solution will fail constantly. AlexChaffee is the only that works for me 100% of the time.

Comment: @Mark I too found that ```removeItemAtURL:``` didn't work while evicted, but ```trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:``` does.

Answer (score 16):

Copied from the ["Deleting a Document"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW4) section of the [Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
    [fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:fileURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
        error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL* writingURL) {
        NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:writingURL error:nil];
    }];
});
```

N.B.: "When you delete a document from storage, your code should approximate what UIDocument does for reading and writing operations. It should perform the deletion asynchronously on a background queue, and it should use file coordination."

Comment: If you are using a `UIDocument` there is no need to implement your own NSFileCoordinator it is already baked into `UIDocument`. Using your method  is expensive results in multiple `NSFileCoordinator` instances. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileCoordinators/FileCoordinators.html

Comment: @Joseph I am wondering, from your answer above, is that why I am either unable to delete an item, which is an object of UIDocument, from iCloud or the app hangs when trying to do so? My related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821141/app-hangs-deleting-icloud-document-when-following-guideline-using-nsfilecoordi)

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT 3** come from @AlexChaffee 's answer

```
func deleteZipFile(with filePath: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
        fileCoordinator.coordinate(writingItemAt: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath), options: NSFileCoordinator.WritingOptions.forDeleting, error: nil) {
            writingURL in
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: writingURL)
            } catch {
                DLog("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:url destinationURL:nil error:nil]
```

Source:
http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/ios5-tech-talk-michael-jurewitz-on-icloud-storage/

Comment: That doesn't work- iCloud now ignores this call with a nil-value destinationURL.

Answer (score 0):

See Apple documentation of "Managing the Life-Cyle of a Document" under 'Deleting a Document."

Comment: To avoid excessive google usage, here's direct link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW4